# How to received only primary labeled emails

Tags: gmail

My Nexus 5 battery drains very fast when I am using the Gmail app. Even after I turned synced off. Is there any way to get emails that belongs to primary category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though it's unlikely that Gmail is the cause of your battery drain, here are the steps to minimize the notification spam:

1. In Gmail app tap on the upper-left corner "hamburger" button to open the sidebar, then scroll down and tap on "Settings":
   [image: screenshot]  [image: screenshot]
   *click for larger images*
2. Tap on your account and ensure the `Notifications` option is checked:
   [image: screenshot 2]
   [click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK2Ta.jpg)
3. Tap on `Inbox sound & vibrate` menu, and un-check the `Notify for every message` option.
4. Go back to your e-mail list, and navigate to the "Primary" inbox.  Tap the 3-dot button on upper-right corner and tap on `Label settings` menu:
   [image: screenshot]
   [click for larger image](https://i.imgur.com/EUx8TY1.jpg)
5. Under the "Notifications" section enable Label notifications, and set up sound/vibration to your liking:
   [image: screenshot]
   [click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1JSo.jpg)
6. Go back to your main inbox.
7. Open the sidebar (see step 1) and select one of the other labels.
8. Tap on menu button, go to `Label settings`, and un-check the "Label notifications" to disable them for this specific label only:
   [image: screenshot]
   [click for larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNLuc.jpg)
9. Go back, and repeat steps 6 through 8 for every label (other than "Primary.")

You should now only receive notifications for your Primary inbox, and you will be only notified once until you dismiss the notification (as opposed to for every new e-mail.)

Comment: "`Even though it's unlikely that Gmail is the cause of your battery drain`" <-- Was just about to write this myself. I've seen a lot of different Google services drain battery but Gmail has never been an issue. I'd say something else is doind it. Worth looking in `Settings>Battery` and seeing what is doing it.